# Crystal Reports: Inverted type when printing on certain printers

Tags: crystal-reports, printing

I inherited a .NET project with Crystal Reports which I upgraded from VS2005 to VS2008. Suddenly, some of the labels are inverting (ie. white text on black 'highlighting'). This is only on one printer. The rest of the printers print normally.

Is there a setting on the VS2008 CR designer that I'm missing (that only the one printer picks up on), or is this a printer driver issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue could possibly be either, though if the report is working fine on other printers consistently I would look at the driver first.  Some printers when given a stream of specific data will invert text, or will do so when given specific font data.  This issue makes me think specifically of receipt printers that have limited font capabilities, is this a receipt printer?

Have you tried making a minor adjustment to the labels in question such as changing the font type or size to see if the text is still inverted on that particular printer?  If that doesn't change your output, try uninstalling and reinstalling the print driver and resetting the printer itself.

Comment: The inversion occurred when upgrading the project from VS2005 to 2008 (and the corresponding versions of CR). I'm not sure of the exact printer make and model, but it's a standard office printer, not a specialised one.

Comment: The make of the printer is Xerox Able 3321. It looks like this sort of thing does occur with other software as well.

Comment: I guess the labels became corrupted when I migrated the project from VS2005. I created new ones and now the problem is gone. It's a bit like magic (CR sometimes is) but now it works. Thanks for your input :)

Comment: I've seen weirder things with CR - glad you got it figured out. :)